# Regex to parse html source in JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to fetch values from a web page source file this is the html rules i have

```
e=d.select("li[id=result_48]");
e=d.select("div[id=result_48]");
```

this is the html tag

```
<li id="result_48" data-asin="0781774047" class="s-result-item">
<div id="result_48" data-asin="0781774047" class="s-result-item">
```

what i want to do is whatever comes in place of "li" or "div" i want to get the value inside the id .. so i want to use RegX in place of "li" or "div"

So the Jsoup element should check the id=result_48 and if something comes like that i want the data. how can i do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you use [getElementById("result_48")](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29) as id are unique in html?

Comment: <li id="result_48" data-asin="0781774047" class="s-result-item"> 
This is the html tag .
<div id="result_48" data-asin="0781774047" class="s-result-item">

Comment: I can't see any regex in your ask, you ask for the id `result_48`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with different order of attributes. Might have missed some cases so test with your actual data.
Assume that there are no spaces and quotes in the id attribute.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] lines = {
            "<li id=\"result_48\" data-asin=\"0781774047\" class=\"s-result-item\">",
            "<div id=\"result_48\" data-asin=\"0781774047\" class=\"s-result-item\">",
            "<div data-asin=\"0781774047\" id=\"result_48\" class=\"s-result-item\">",
            "<div data-asin=\"0781774047\" class=\"s-result-item\" id=\"result_48\">" };
    for (String str : lines) {
        System.out.println(extractId(str));
    }
}

private static String extractId(String line) {
    String regex = "";
    regex = regex + "(?:[<](?:li|div)).*id=\""; // match start until id="
    regex = regex + "([^\\s^\"]+)"; // capture the id inside quotes (exclude
                                    // spaces and quote)
    regex = regex + "(?:.*\">)"; // match any characters until the end ">
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```